# How to increase the height of table row according to screens?

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to know how can I increase the height of table row so it looks proportionate in larger screen sizes. Currently all of the textviews and edittexts(placed in table rows) appear on the left side of the screen instead of occuping the whole screen( only in larger screen sizes).
Here is the xml I am working with:

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">     

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@color/black_background">

<TableLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    >
  <TableRow    android:id="@+id/TableRow01" 
               android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


  <TextView  android:id="@+id/name"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textSize="20sp"
             android:textColor="@color/white" 
             android:visibility="visible" 
             android:text="@string/Name" 
             android:layout_weight="0.2"
             android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" 
             android:layout_marginTop="22dp"/>

 <EditText   android:id="@+id/myName"
             android:layout_width="120dip"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textSize="20sp"
             android:visibility="visible" 
             android:layout_weight="0.3"
             android:inputType="number" 
             android:textColor="@color/black_background" 
             android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
             android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

 <TextView   android:id="@+id/error1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textSize="18sp"
             android:textColor="@color/red" 
             android:visibility="visible" 
             android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

  </TableRow>
 <TableRow    android:id="@+id/TableRow02" 
               android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">


  <TextView  android:id="@+id/address"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textSize="20sp"
             android:visibility="visible"
             android:textColor="@color/white" 
             android:text="@string/address" 
             android:layout_weight="0.2"
             android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" android:layout_marginTop="22dp"/>

 <EditText   android:id="@+id/address"
             android:layout_width="120dip"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textSize="20sp"
             android:visibility="visible" 
             android:inputType="number" 
             android:textColor="@color/black_background" 
             android:layout_weight="0.8"
             android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

  </TableRow>
</TableLayout>           

    </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 30):

Use

```
android:minHeight="60px"
```

On `TableRow` tag

```
<TableRow android:id="@+id/task1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:minHeight="60px" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Answer (score 7):

Please go through this link, i think it will help you out.
http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=307

Please note that the children of a `TableLayout` cannot specify their width – which is always `FILL_PARENT`. However, the height can be defined by a child, which defaults to `WRAP_CONTENT`. If the child is a `TableRow`, then the height is always `WRAP_CONTENT`.

**So if you use `TableLayout` with `TableRows` you can’t really can’t set the width/height (`width=FILL_PARENT`, and `height=WRAP_CONTENT`).**

By the way, a TableRow is just a subclass of LinearLayout. What you can do is specify the behavior of the column to shrink and/or stretch or not. You can also hide a column by calling setColumnCollapsed on a TableLayout, and passing it the column index. All column indices start at 0, and you can have empty columns.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use android:layout_weight.  In the code below for example, the left button is twice as big as the right button:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="hai" />
    <Button android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="longer sentence" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Add the following properties to all your `TableRow`s:

```
android:layout_height = "0dp"
android:layout_weight = "1"
```

It stretches all your `TableRow`s to occupy the entire parent height.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `android:layout_weight` of each `TableRow` to 1. Then change the height of `TableLayout` as you like. It works fine for me!

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `android:layout_weight` to TableRow and give equal value to all table rows. Table rows will be distributed in remaining space of linear layout.

Ensure, you have set below attributes to TableLayout

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```