# How to set background colour of view to fill its parent?

Tags: java, android, tablerow

I have a TableLayout, creating this table: [image: TbaleRow]

And I simply want the background color to fill the space given, rather than matching the content (however it does extend horizontally?)

How would I go about doing this? I set the individual TextViews to fill_parent, but that caused errors...

Edit: XML is [here:](http://pastebin.com/sSBLKfpd), as it's pretty big

Comment: Can you post your xml code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22149100/1235910

Comment: what space ? can you please clarify what you need to do

Comment: The whitespace between cells in the table, I'd like it to be filled with the colour of the text in the cell